# Changing project's dirs breaks precompiled file creation

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I use MSVC2017 (with MSVC2013 toolchain, if it's matters).
So, I have created new solution with "static lib" project and a console app. At this step it works.

Now, I changed some project's paths for the lib project:

Output directory: $(SolutionDir)BuildDebug
Intermediate directory: $(OutDir)\Debug
I added following includes into pch.h:

- #include <windows.h>
- #include <inttypes.h>
- #include <cstdlib>
- #include <stdexcept>

I added reference to my lib and lib's include dir inside console app. Now Studio cannot compile my project, showing a lot of errors about

> error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'LONG'

and related.
I found that there is no .pch file anywhere.
I also created test solution with same static lib alone and changed same paths. It seems to compiling successfully, but Intellisense underlines "LONG" with red, saying "it's undefined".
May be someone faced the same problem.

Update: I just tried to create a new solution. I added static lib project, then I added simple file with single function `int func(LONG v)`. It seems to compile. But then I add console app to the solution, link it against static lib, and it's not compile, saying that

> error C2065: 'LONG': undeclared identifier

Update 2: I've found that static lib files don't see <windows.h> added into precompiled header. So I included it into my header directly and added `typedef struct IUnknown IUnknown;` before windows.h, because of new error related to `IUnknown`. It seems to work. But I still don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pre-compiled headers" are a build-speed optimization. If they're giving you problems, you can always turn off their use temporarily. When they're turned off, the `.pch` is no longer used, but the `.h` is still used.

I expect you'll still have the missing `LONG`, since it's not even in the `.h`

For your sanity, it might be useful to use explicit names for your precompiled `.h`. I'm not sure if VS2017 already uses `pch.h` by default, or it it still uses `stdafx.h`. Either way, that's just a default. If you want, you can also rename them to `staticlib.h/.pch` and `executable.h/.pch` to avoid confusion. The compiler has no default name for the pch; it relies on compiler switches `/Yc` (create) and `/Yu` (use).

Comment: I hoping that disabling precompiling header is last measure. Also, I still want to know what's the problem to be sure I haven't done something very bad (and nothing else is broken). By default MSVC2017 names precompiled header pch.h, but I don't think that it is a problem - I can still include into it other headers like <string>, and it works.

Comment: @qloq: Disabling PCH is a step in troubleshooting the problem. Once all non-PCH problems are solved, you can turn it back on. As for the naming problem, the issue might be that you have **two** files both named `pch.h`, one for your static lib and one for your  executable.

Comment: I tried to disable pch. Works as expected (in the same way), except that I still need to add that typedef before Windows.h. By the way, I use the only single precompiled header (in static lib).